# Receiving notifications when user edits a node?

Tags: nodes, notifications

Newbie here!
I'm running a site on Drupal 7 (iloveqatar.net) and users have the ability to submit their own content (News, Events, etc...).

I'm facing a couple of issues.

1) When users submit new content that's in moderation to be approved, I don't get any notification. What's the best module to a) send emails to moderators / admins so they're aware there is content that needs to be approved and b) Display the notification on the site (like an unread message counter).

Right now I click on "Needs Review" on the admin bar on the top of the site every few hours just in case theres new content.

2) This one is the more problematic issue. When a user submits an event for example, and it's then approved, the user still has the ability to edit his/her post, which then creates a draft that needs to moderated and approved. However since it's creating a draft of an existing note, I'm not seeing it under the 'needs review' table. I actually have to go to that specific event and then edit it to approve the changes. Of course that's no good for me, because I can't go around checking every single post just in case there's an edit.

Does anyone know of a solution for this so that I can get notified and/or it shows up in 'needs review' ?

Please do let me know if I need to include any additional information to get help.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Are you using the Workflow Moderation module?

Comment: Hi there,
I'm using workbench moderation

Comment: You should split out #2 into a separate question, though, something sounds wrong with your setup, as that is a fairly normal workflow type.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of the [Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) module integrate with [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules).  I am not sure if [the patch](https://drupal.org/node/1226688) is in the stable tree, or whether you need to use the dev version, though.

Assuming you have a version that supports this, then

- add a new rule
- for the reaction, choose **Node: After moderation transtion**
- for the action, choose **Send mail**
- if needed, you can add conditions based on the old and/or new moderation state.

After that, just configure the conditions and the email that gets sent out.

Comment: I'll give that a go and then report back :)

Comment: Alright, almost great news.

1- I'm receiving emails when there is a change. However, I'm not sure how to get the emails to include a link to what's changed. Is there a tag I need to include in the message body?

Comment: Alright, almost great news.

1- I'm receiving emails when there is a change. However, I'm not sure how to get the emails to include a link to what's changed. Is there a tag I need to include in the message body?

2- you recommended choosing After moderation transition as the reaction, but doesn't that mean I'll receive a notification 'after' I've moderated it? There's another option which is, 'After updating existing content'. 

3- I added the condition, 'Content is published'. 
It asked for extra information like Data Types and Data Selector but I didn't touch it and clicked save.

Comment: @amnesia You need to play with the reaction rules to get it the way you want.  It will depend on how your workflow is defined.  You may also need multiple rules (this is what we normally do).  Email.  When you edit the email template, you can use tokens (called replacement patterns on the edit form).  [node:url] should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Notify module is good solution for your 1st problem.It is sending mails when any new content or comment added into your site.
 Check the module on https://drupal.org/project/notify.